# Why inorder traversal of binary search tree guarantee to have non-decreasing order?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

TL;DR My ultimate problem is to find the two nodes on a proper binary tree (i.e. itself has at least two nodes) that one is only greater than input, and the other only less than input. (cont. under the line)

---

To implement that, I personally *asserted* that literally if you draw a tree (decently), you see horizontally the one on the right is by all means greater than any one on its left.

In other words, quoting from Wikipedia (Binary search tree):

> The key in each node must be greater than all keys stored in the left sub-tree, and smaller than all keys in the right sub-tree.

And it seems to only guaranteed to be true locally. With a figure like this:

```
          A
       /    \
      B      C
    /   \  /   \
   D     E F    G
 /   \
H     I
```

*(Letters have no order, i.e. just for structure)*

By locally I mean when we talk about node E, it's guaranteed that D (with F and G) is smaller than E, but what about C, F, G compared to E, is that also guaranteed?

This seems quite intuitive (that F,C,G are all greater than E), but I don't find anyway to prove that, so is there any counterexample or theoretical proof? Any existed theorems or suggestions?

---

**EDIT:** I finally find this equivalent to why is in-order traversal of a binary search tree has a non-decreasing order.

Comment: IMO this is more a question for [Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MarcelG, um then yes, but anyway Data Science has a lower popularity compared to SO, right? I'm also thinking about move to Mathematics, waiting for suggestions here :-\

Comment: The definition itself for AVL tree or for any kind of binary search tree says that value on the left and all its descendants must be smaller. Therefore it is axiom, you do not have to prove it.

Comment: Binary **Search** Tree. You can prove it by induction on the depth of this node

Comment: @libik, isn't that only guaranteed to be true for locally applied to a node comparing its left and right child?

Comment: The thing you can try to prove is for example this : "If I add x random numbers with this approach, is it garaunteed that all the values on the left will be smaller and all values on the right will be higher?" 

But if you already have structure, which you call AVL Tree, you do not have prove it is AVL Tree.

Comment: @libik, I think it's pretty easy to prove that property of BST if you treat the node as root, then all the thing on its right must be larger, but what about the subtree started with parent's sibling node and parent's parent's node ...? Any clue?

Comment: @libik, quoted from wikipedia: "... states that the key in each node must be greater than all keys stored in the left sub-tree, and smaller than all keys in the right sub-tree." This as a axiom is only when you treat the current node as root and don't think about its counterpart, right?

Comment: @YiFei - I am not sure I understand you correctly. Wikipedia says it all, EACH node have these properties, no matter if it is root or not. Maybe edit your question and ask more concrete question.

Comment: @libik, thanks, I gave an example, hope that help.

Comment: @YiFei - states that the **key in each node** must be **greater** than all keys stored in the **left** sub-tree, and **smaller** than all keys in the **right** sub-tree -> Your tree does not satisfy that. Look at your root node - B is greater than A and is on the left. It is not possible.

Comment: I didn't specify the number, i.e. just to demonstrate structure I don't imply that A>B or A<B, since if I do, I would then give a concrete example then the following question are then not valid (I want a proof and can't find counterexample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems quite intuitive (that F,C,G are all greater than E), but I don't find anyway to prove that, so is there any counterexample or theoretical proof? Any existed theorems or suggestions?

1. F > A — definition of BST ("key in *each* node must be … smaller than *all* keys in the right sub-tree")
2. E < A — definition of BST ("key in *each* node must be greater than *all* keys stored in the left sub-tree")
3. E < A < F — transitivity

And so on for C and G

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between a "binary tree" and a "binary search tree" to be precise about it.

A *binary search tree* has the property you're looking for; all nodes in the left branch are smaller than all nodes in the right branch. If it's weren't the case, you couldn't use the search method usually associated -- that is, look at a node, and if you're looking for a smaller node, go left, if you're looking for a larger node, go right. I think both a basic BST, plus balanced trees like AVL and red-black, all observe this same property.

There are other binary tree data structures which aren't "Binary Search Trees" -- for example, a min-heap and max-heap are both binary trees, but the 'left is smaller than right' constraint is not met all the way through the tree. Heaps are used to find the smallest or largest element in a set, so you only normally reason about the node at the top of the tree.

As to a proof, I guess there is this; if you accept that the search algorithm works, then we can show that this property must hold. For instance, in this tree;

```
      a
     / \
    b   n
   / \
  c   d
```

then let's say you wanted to prove that `d` is smaller than `n`, or any child. Imagine you were searching for `d` and you were at `a`. Obviously, you compare `a` to `d` and find that `d` is smaller -- that's how you know to traverse left, to `b`. So right there we've got to have faith that the entire left tree (`b` and under) must all be smaller than `a`. The same argument for the right hand side and numbers greater than a.

So `left-children(a) < a < right-children(a)`

In terrible pseudo-proof...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, you have same tree without E:

```
         A
       /   \
      B     C
    /     /   \
   D     F     G
 /   \
H     I
```

Now you insert this E that greater than B. What if E greater than A also? In this case it will be inserted to right subtree of A, well? But while E is in right subtree of B, it less than A:

```
         A
       /   \
      B     C
     / \   / \
    D   E F   G
   / \
  H   I
```

Comment: Thank you as well as @erickson, by applying the property on the sufficient high parent node, we can draw a final conclusion that the property actually works globally around the tree.